# Accurev - why file status is incorrect?

Tags: accurev

I have modified few files locally by windows copy command but when I saw the status of modified files in AccuRev it is still shown as backed. Eventhough the file is modified then why it show the status as backed.

Any clue?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 4):

You copied a file into your workspace that has an older timestamp than the workspace scan threshold time.

If you turn off "Timestamp Optimization" and click refresh, the file will appear as modified.

Or if you run the command "accurev touch " and then hit refresh, the file will appear as modified.